# css glitch effect with svg not working on chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, svg, safari

im having issues with a glitch effect i want to make for a svg logo but its not working in google chrome while on safari it works fine. i dont know how to explain it so pls have a look in this pen: http://codepen.io/Separator/pen/WGLzAx

*heres some code as stackoverflow suggests:

```
body {
  background: black;
  font-family: 'Varela', sans-serif;
}

.glitch {
  color: white;
  font-size: 100px;
  position: relative;
  width: 400px;
    z-index: 999;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

@-webkit-keyframes noise-anim {
  0% {
    clip: rect(20px, 9999px, 216px, 0);
  }
  1% {
    clip: rect(64px, 9999px, 105px, 0);
  }
  2% {
    clip: rect(57px, 9999px, 25px, 0);
  }
  3% {
    clip: rect(8px, 9999px, 67px, 0);
  }
  4% {
    clip: rect(73px, 9999px, 45px, 0);
  }
  5% {
    clip: rect(31px, 9999px, 250px, 0);
  }
  6% {
    clip: rect(16px, 9999px, 223px, 0);
  }
  7% {
    clip: rect(33px, 9999px, 97px, 0);
  }
  8% {
    clip: rect(62px, 9999px, 2px, 0);
  }
  9% {
    clip: rect(35px, 9999px, 251px, 0);
  }
  10% {
    clip: rect(96px, 9999px, 99px, 0);
  }
  11% {
    clip: rect(69px, 9999px, 378px, 0);
  }
  12% {
    clip: rect(81px, 9999px, 116px, 0);
  }
  13% {
    clip: rect(34px, 9999px, 223px, 0);
  }
  14% {
    clip: rect(58px, 9999px, 167px, 0);
  }
  15% {
    clip: rect(44px, 9999px, 93px, 0);
  }
  16% {
    clip: rect(41px, 9999px, 334px, 0);
  }
  17% {
    clip: rect(2px, 9999px, 266px, 0);
  }
  18% {
    clip: rect(68px, 9999px, 199px, 0);
  }
  19% {
    clip: rect(16px, 9999px, 19px, 0);
  }
  20% {
    clip: rect(61px, 9999px, 290px, 0);
  }
  21% {
    clip: rect(56px, 9999px, 183px, 0);
  }
  22% {
    clip: rect(64px, 9999px, 391px, 0);
  }
  23% {
    clip: rect(68px, 9999px, 15px, 0);
  }
  24% {
    clip: rect(98px, 9999px, 326px, 0);
  }
  25% {
    clip: rect(32px, 9999px, 48px, 0);
  }
  26% {
    clip: rect(91px, 9999px, 315px, 0);
  }
  27% {
    clip: rect(8px, 9999px, 309px, 0);
  }
  28% {
    clip: rect(60px, 9999px, 89px, 0);
  }
  29% {
    clip: rect(62px, 9999px, 207px, 0);
  }
  30% {
    clip: rect(96px, 9999px, 84px, 0);
  }
  31% {
    clip: rect(63px, 9999px, 27px, 0);
  }
  32% {
    clip: rect(93px, 9999px, 33px, 0);
  }
  33% {
    clip: rect(67px, 9999px, 287px, 0);
  }
  34% {
    clip: rect(24px, 9999px, 74px, 0);
  }
  35% {
    clip: rect(86px, 9999px, 307px, 0);
  }
  36% {
    clip: rect(73px, 9999px, 73px, 0);
  }
  37% {
    clip: rect(6px, 9999px, 9px, 0);
  }
  38% {
    clip: rect(13px, 9999px, 323px, 0);
  }
  39% {
    clip: rect(46px, 9999px, 306px, 0);
  }
  40% {
    clip: rect(76px, 9999px, 351px, 0);
  }
  41% {
    clip: rect(75px, 9999px, 100px, 0);
  }
  42% {
    clip: rect(98px, 9999px, 393px, 0);
  }
  43% {
    clip: rect(14px, 9999px, 361px, 0);
  }
  44% {
    clip: rect(98px, 9999px, 385px, 0);
  }
  45% {
    clip: rect(14px, 9999px, 136px, 0);
  }
  46% {
    clip: rect(68px, 9999px, 132px, 0);
  }
  47% {
    clip: rect(81px, 9999px, 75px, 0);
  }
  48% {
    clip: rect(11px, 9999px, 210px, 0);
  }
  49% {
    clip: rect(48px, 9999px, 108px, 0);
  }
  50% {
    clip: rect(66px, 9999px, 20px, 0);
  }
  51% {
    clip: rect(35px, 9999px, 94px, 0);
  }
  52% {
    clip: rect(26px, 9999px, 309px, 0);
  }
  53% {
    clip: rect(27px, 9999px, 20px, 0);
  }
  54% {
    clip: rect(21px, 9999px, 150px, 0);
  }
  55% {
    clip: rect(88px, 9999px, 202px, 0);
  }
  56% {
    clip: rect(11px, 9999px, 323px, 0);
  }
  57% {
    clip: rect(6px, 9999px, 348px, 0);
  }
  58% {
    clip: rect(7px, 9999px, 395px, 0);
  }
  59% {
    clip: rect(7px, 9999px, 42px, 0);
  }
  60% {
    clip: rect(24px, 9999px, 238px, 0);
  }
  61% {
    clip: rect(5px, 9999px, 372px, 0);
  }
  62% {
    clip: rect(25px, 9999px, 113px, 0);
  }
  63% {
    clip: rect(54px, 9999px, 388px, 0);
  }
  64% {
    clip: rect(93px, 9999px, 97px, 0);
  }
  65% {
    clip: rect(18px, 9999px, 141px, 0);
  }
  66% {
    clip: rect(63px, 9999px, 58px, 0);
  }
  67% {
    clip: rect(81px, 9999px, 354px, 0);
  }
  68% {
    clip: rect(66px, 9999px, 390px, 0);
  }
  69% {
    clip: rect(17px, 9999px, 315px, 0);
  }
  70% {
    clip: rect(46px, 9999px, 46px, 0);
  }
  71% {
    clip: rect(71px, 9999px, 148px, 0);
  }
  72% {
    clip: rect(97px, 9999px, 234px, 0);
  }
  73% {
    clip: rect(70px, 9999px, 92px, 0);
  }
  74% {
    clip: rect(37px, 9999px, 229px, 0);
  }
  75% {
    clip: rect(70px, 9999px, 195px, 0);
  }
  76% {
    clip: rect(67px, 9999px, 263px, 0);
  }
  77% {
    clip: rect(57px, 9999px, 138px, 0);
  }
  78% {
    clip: rect(41px, 9999px, 42px, 0);
  }
  79% {
    clip: rect(13px, 9999px, 364px, 0);
  }
  80% {
    clip: rect(11px, 9999px, 343px, 0);
  }
  81% {
    clip: rect(78px, 9999px, 239px, 0);
  }
  82% {
    clip: rect(85px, 9999px, 152px, 0);
  }
  83% {
    clip: rect(67px, 9999px, 125px, 0);
  }
  84% {
    clip: rect(55px, 9999px, 280px, 0);
  }
  85% {
    clip: rect(35px, 9999px, 107px, 0);
  }
  86% {
    clip: rect(45px, 9999px, 139px, 0);
  }
  87% {
    clip: rect(21px, 9999px, 221px, 0);
  }
  88% {
    clip: rect(66px, 9999px, 216px, 0);
  }
  89% {
    clip: rect(84px, 9999px, 346px, 0);
  }
  90% {
    clip: rect(26px, 9999px, 177px, 0);
  }
  91% {
    clip: rect(92px, 9999px, 104px, 0);
  }
  92% {
    clip: rect(33px, 9999px, 381px, 0);
  }
  93% {
    clip: rect(79px, 9999px, 103px, 0);
  }
  94% {
    clip: rect(72px, 9999px, 389px, 0);
  }
  95% {
    clip: rect(41px, 9999px, 116px, 0);
  }
  96% {
    clip: rect(56px, 9999px, 5px, 0);
  }
  97% {
    clip: rect(16px, 9999px, 283px, 0);
  }
  98% {
    clip: rect(28px, 9999px, 69px, 0);
  }
  99% {
    clip: rect(78px, 9999px, 264px, 0);
  }
  100% {
    clip: rect(91px, 9999px, 262px, 0);
  }
}
.glitch:after {
  content: url("../hack.svg");
  position: absolute;
  left: 2px;
  box-shadow: -5px 0 red;
  top: 0;
  color: white;
  background: black;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(0, 900px, 0, 0);
  -webkit-animation: noise-anim 2s infinite linear alternate-reverse;
}

@-webkit-keyframes noise-anim-2 {
  0% {
    clip: rect(27px, 9999px, 55px, 0);
  }
  1% {
    clip: rect(21px, 9999px, 44px, 0);
  }
  2% {
    clip: rect(18px, 9999px, 82px, 0);
  }
  3% {
    clip: rect(51px, 9999px, 38px, 0);
  }
  4% {
    clip: rect(100px, 9999px, 69px, 0);
  }
  5% {
    clip: rect(16px, 9999px, 44px, 0);
  }
  6% {
    clip: rect(38px, 9999px, 70px, 0);
  }
  7% {
    clip: rect(87px, 9999px, 72px, 0);
  }
  8% {
    clip: rect(84px, 9999px, 46px, 0);
  }
  9% {
    clip: rect(17px, 9999px, 7px, 0);
  }
  10% {
    clip: rect(79px, 9999px, 36px, 0);
  }
  11% {
    clip: rect(37px, 9999px, 34px, 0);
  }
  12% {
    clip: rect(60px, 9999px, 25px, 0);
  }
  13% {
    clip: rect(92px, 9999px, 34px, 0);
  }
  14% {
    clip: rect(20px, 9999px, 72px, 0);
  }
  15% {
    clip: rect(3px, 9999px, 5px, 0);
  }
  16% {
    clip: rect(9px, 9999px, 76px, 0);
  }
  17% {
    clip: rect(26px, 9999px, 60px, 0);
  }
  18% {
    clip: rect(5px, 9999px, 73px, 0);
  }
  19% {
    clip: rect(34px, 9999px, 37px, 0);
  }
  20% {
    clip: rect(24px, 9999px, 62px, 0);
  }
  21% {
    clip: rect(6px, 9999px, 83px, 0);
  }
  22% {
    clip: rect(40px, 9999px, 27px, 0);
  }
  23% {
    clip: rect(23px, 9999px, 67px, 0);
  }
  24% {
    clip: rect(92px, 9999px, 47px, 0);
  }
  25% {
    clip: rect(41px, 9999px, 47px, 0);
  }
  26% {
    clip: rect(93px, 9999px, 30px, 0);
  }
  27% {
    clip: rect(67px, 9999px, 28px, 0);
  }
  28% {
    clip: rect(54px, 9999px, 79px, 0);
  }
  29% {
    clip: rect(74px, 9999px, 26px, 0);
  }
  30% {
    clip: rect(22px, 9999px, 81px, 0);
  }
  31% {
    clip: rect(76px, 9999px, 60px, 0);
  }
  32% {
    clip: rect(60px, 9999px, 12px, 0);
  }
  33% {
    clip: rect(47px, 9999px, 45px, 0);
  }
  34% {
    clip: rect(9px, 9999px, 64px, 0);
  }
  35% {
    clip: rect(46px, 9999px, 7px, 0);
  }
  36% {
    clip: rect(38px, 9999px, 73px, 0);
  }
  37% {
    clip: rect(66px, 9999px, 35px, 0);
  }
  38% {
    clip: rect(8px, 9999px, 14px, 0);
  }
  39% {
    clip: rect(89px, 9999px, 27px, 0);
  }
  40% {
    clip: rect(8px, 9999px, 66px, 0);
  }
  41% {
    clip: rect(30px, 9999px, 33px, 0);
  }
  42% {
    clip: rect(59px, 9999px, 51px, 0);
  }
  43% {
    clip: rect(25px, 9999px, 100px, 0);
  }
  44% {
    clip: rect(83px, 9999px, 82px, 0);
  }
  45% {
    clip: rect(4px, 9999px, 36px, 0);
  }
  46% {
    clip: rect(99px, 9999px, 73px, 0);
  }
  47% {
    clip: rect(78px, 9999px, 59px, 0);
  }
  48% {
    clip: rect(40px, 9999px, 9px, 0);
  }
  49% {
    clip: rect(24px, 9999px, 62px, 0);
  }
  50% {
    clip: rect(82px, 9999px, 11px, 0);
  }
  51% {
    clip: rect(39px, 9999px, 99px, 0);
  }
  52% {
    clip: rect(36px, 9999px, 95px, 0);
  }
  53% {
    clip: rect(59px, 9999px, 32px, 0);
  }
  54% {
    clip: rect(89px, 9999px, 43px, 0);
  }
  55% {
    clip: rect(5px, 9999px, 64px, 0);
  }
  56% {
    clip: rect(90px, 9999px, 70px, 0);
  }
  57% {
    clip: rect(46px, 9999px, 21px, 0);
  }
  58% {
    clip: rect(23px, 9999px, 18px, 0);
  }
  59% {
    clip: rect(47px, 9999px, 4px, 0);
  }
  60% {
    clip: rect(29px, 9999px, 47px, 0);
  }
  61% {
    clip: rect(97px, 9999px, 48px, 0);
  }
  62% {
    clip: rect(8px, 9999px, 99px, 0);
  }
  63% {
    clip: rect(98px, 9999px, 37px, 0);
  }
  64% {
    clip: rect(56px, 9999px, 59px, 0);
  }
  65% {
    clip: rect(51px, 9999px, 17px, 0);
  }
  66% {
    clip: rect(77px, 9999px, 47px, 0);
  }
  67% {
    clip: rect(38px, 9999px, 98px, 0);
  }
  68% {
    clip: rect(42px, 9999px, 11px, 0);
  }
  69% {
    clip: rect(58px, 9999px, 89px, 0);
  }
  70% {
    clip: rect(39px, 9999px, 94px, 0);
  }
  71% {
    clip: rect(74px, 9999px, 90px, 0);
  }
  72% {
    clip: rect(92px, 9999px, 53px, 0);
  }
  73% {
    clip: rect(20px, 9999px, 11px, 0);
  }
  74% {
    clip: rect(1px, 9999px, 60px, 0);
  }
  75% {
    clip: rect(92px, 9999px, 30px, 0);
  }
  76% {
    clip: rect(91px, 9999px, 48px, 0);
  }
  77% {
    clip: rect(44px, 9999px, 14px, 0);
  }
  78% {
    clip: rect(76px, 9999px, 7px, 0);
  }
  79% {
    clip: rect(63px, 9999px, 90px, 0);
  }
  80% {
    clip: rect(71px, 9999px, 77px, 0);
  }
  81% {
    clip: rect(10px, 9999px, 10px, 0);
  }
  82% {
    clip: rect(100px, 9999px, 84px, 0);
  }
  83% {
    clip: rect(56px, 9999px, 70px, 0);
  }
  84% {
    clip: rect(33px, 9999px, 14px, 0);
  }
  85% {
    clip: rect(9px, 9999px, 6px, 0);
  }
  86% {
    clip: rect(2px, 9999px, 52px, 0);
  }
  87% {
    clip: rect(78px, 9999px, 20px, 0);
  }
  88% {
    clip: rect(58px, 9999px, 35px, 0);
  }
  89% {
    clip: rect(96px, 9999px, 29px, 0);
  }
  90% {
    clip: rect(13px, 9999px, 74px, 0);
  }
  91% {
    clip: rect(66px, 9999px, 74px, 0);
  }
  92% {
    clip: rect(5px, 9999px, 31px, 0);
  }
  93% {
    clip: rect(71px, 9999px, 19px, 0);
  }
  94% {
    clip: rect(53px, 9999px, 86px, 0);
  }
  95% {
    clip: rect(84px, 9999px, 33px, 0);
  }
  96% {
    clip: rect(83px, 9999px, 10px, 0);
  }
  97% {
    clip: rect(51px, 9999px, 38px, 0);
  }
  98% {
    clip: rect(17px, 9999px, 55px, 0);
  }
  99% {
    clip: rect(64px, 9999px, 37px, 0);
  }
  100% {
    clip: rect(12px, 9999px, 9px, 0);
  }
}
.glitch:before {
  content: url("../hack.svg");
  position: absolute;
  left: -2px;
  box-shadow: 5px 0 red;
  top: 0;
  color: white;
  background: black;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(0, 900px, 0, 0);
  -webkit-animation: noise-anim-2 3s infinite linear alternate-reverse;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`clip` is defunct. You are supposed to use `clip-path` now.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/clip

Try changing that and see if it makes a difference.